# ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Suppose I have the following ODE:
$$Au(x)- Bxu'(x) - Cu''(x)=0,$$
where $A,B,C>0$ are constants. If $u'(x)$ would not be multiplied by the $x$ factor, it would have been easy to obtain the general solution, but now I have no clue how to solve this ODE. What is here the best  strategy to obtain the general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C>0$ you can rewrite your equation:
$$
u''(x) = au(x)-bxu'(x)
$$
where $a=\frac{A}{C}$ and $b=\frac{B}{C}$. Introduce the phase coordinates: $(v(x),w(x))=(u(x),u'(x))$ and you obtain a system of non autonomous first order ODE:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cl}v'(x) &= w(x) \\ w'(x) &=av(x)-bxw(x)
\end{array}\right.
$$
which in matrix notations is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}v'(x)\\w'(x)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\a&-bx\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v(x)\\w(x)\end{pmatrix}
$$

I now assume starting conditions $(v(0),w(0))=(v_0,w_0)$. The general solution of this equation is given by,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}v(x)\\w(x)\end{pmatrix}=M(x)\begin{pmatrix}v_0\\w_0\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $M(x)$ is the resolvant of the system, i.e. the matrix solution of
$$
M'(x)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\a&-bx\end{pmatrix}M(x), \quad M(0)=Id.
$$

**Remark**: If $b=0$ then it is an autonomous ODE (as you observe) and then the resolvant is given by the matrix exponential: $M(x)=\exp\begin{pmatrix}0&t\\at&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you very much!